# Access and change code assigned to buttons/movieclips inside loaded swf - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm loading external swfs in my main swf.
I can access the content (movieclips and buttons) inside but I need to change the links assign to the buttons/movieclips inside this loaded swf dynamically.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Load it like you would load it normally, then use capture phase on the container, something like this:

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var l:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(l);

l.load(new URLRequest("a.swf"));
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler, true);

function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace(MovieClip(e.target).name); //compare whether it is the button you want
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But i need to find the actual url assign to click event of button/mc and then replace it with some additional parameters.

Comment: If you don't have access to the loaded swf, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: I can even find the mcs/buttons inside swf. But I need to access the code assign to these mc/buttons. And this process need to happen on the fly. Is there any way I can detect the click event and change the navigate url at that time?

Comment: The code I posted does exactly that - it detects the click and prevents the default behavior of the button. You would have to execute the code you want from within that listener because, imho, it is not possible to retrieve the value of navigateToURL assign to that button on click.